# ReactNative navigation 5 - how to obtain `navigation.state.params` (upgrade from 1.x)

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Trying to update old react navigation 1.x to current version 5.x.
I need to display different tab icon depend on what value is in `navigation.state.params`, that were used in 1.x version. This value is set in one of the screen using navigation.dispatch(data).

this is simplified code used with navigation 1.x:

```
import {TabBarBottom, TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {MyIcon, AnotherIcon} from './icons.js';

export default TabNavigator({
    Home: {screen: HomeRouter},
    Profile: {screen: ProfileRouter},
}, {
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            const {routeName, params} = navigation.state;
            ...
            if (params.data === 1)  {
                return <AnotherIcon />
            }
            ...
            return <MyIcon />;
        },
    }),
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
});
```

how need to be change to work with React navigation v.5.x? or all I could do is to use React.Context?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the params using the new hook useRoute available in v5.x

[Documentation here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-route)